# CodeIgniter: Displaying Dynamic Errors

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

**Updated:**

**RJZ:**

`TdjxQetc` is the `$activateCode` that comes from the DB so when I run /confirm/ I should be getting Sorry you did not have a correct Activation Code as I am not passing in any var (`$activateCode`) but when I run /confirm/`$activateCode` I should get Thanks your account is now active you may login! and with the else statement

I am thinking that it should be changed and a new model function developed to check if `userActive` has been set to `1` and then display another `$message` so that the link can only be used.

---

**View:**

```
<div class = "messages">
    <?php if($confirmMessage != ''): ?>
        <?php if($confirmError): ?>
            <p class="error">
                <?php echo $confirmMessage; ?>
                </p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="message">
                        <?php $confirmMessage?>
                        </p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function confirm(){

        $activateCode = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $error = FALSE;
        $message = '';

        if($activateCode == '')
        {
            $error = TRUE;
            $message = 'Sorry you did not have a correct Activation Code.';
        }
            $userConfirmed = $this->users_model->confirm_user($activateCode);

            if($userConfirmed){
                $message = 'Thanks your account is now active you may login!';
            }else{
                $error = TRUE;
                $message = 'I am sorry we do not have any details with that Activation Code';
            }
            $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
            $data['pageTitle'] = "User Confirm";
            $data['confirmError'] = $error;
            $data['confirmMessage'] = $message;
            $this->load->view('frontend/assets/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('frontend/user_confirm', $data);
            $this->load->view('frontend/assets/footer');
    }
```

---

I am unsure why I am not getting the validation messages,  I just get my view.  The database is updating to 1.

**View:**

```
<h1><?php echo $companyName; echo nbs(1);?> - <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>

    <p>Error: <?php echo validation_errors();?></p>
```

**Controller:**

```
function confirm(){

        $activateCode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if($activateCode == '')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('userConfirmError', 'Sorry you did not have a correct Activation Code.');
        }
            $userConfirmed = $this->users_model->confirm_user($activateCode);

            if($userConfirmed){
                $this->form_validation->set_message('userConfirmed', 'Thanks your account is now active you may login!');
            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('userRecord', 'I am sorry we do not have any details with that Activation Code');
            }
            $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
            $data['pageTitle'] = "User Confirm";
            $this->load->view('frontend/assets/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('frontend/user_confirm', $data);
            $this->load->view('frontend/assets/footer');
    }
```

**Confirm Function:**

```
function confirm_user($activateCode)
    {
     //Selects the userID where the given URI activateCode = ?

        $this->db->select('userID');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode);

        $result = $this->db->get();

        if($result->num_rows == 1)  // If the above result is = 1 then update the userActive row else it will fail
        {
            $this->db->set('userActive', 1);
            $this->db->where('userActiveCode', $activateCode);

            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
```

**Core Model:**

```
function companyDetails()
    {
        static $details;

        if(!$details)
        {
            $this->db->select('coreCompanyName, coreContactName, coreContactEmail');
            $details = $this->db->get('core')->first_row();
        }
        return $details;
    }
```

Comment: To be sure have you echo'ed form error in you view..?

Comment: @Sudhir I have included my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are kind of making a mountain out of a mole hill here Jess. Let's see what we can do to clean this up:

**Controller Method**

```
function confirm()
{
    $activate_code = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if(!$this->users_model->confirm_user($activate_code))
        $error = true;
    else
        $error = false;

    $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
    $data['pageTitle'] = "User Confirm";
    $data['confirmError'] = $error;
    $this->load->view('frontend/assets/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/user_confirm', $data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/assets/footer');
}
```

**View**

```
<div class = "messages">
    <?php if($confirmError): ?>
        <p class="error">
            Your activation code is invalid.
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
         <p class="message">
            Your account has been activated.
         </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Please add this code to the top of your UserModel::confirm_user method:

```
if($activateCode == '')
   return false;
```

I've simplified your controller method to only two cases -- success or error. There is no need to check activate_code because your model is doing that for you.

In addition, I prefer to keep strings that are only used in views where they belong -- in the view.

Comment: Thanks for that,  I have tried that but when I try /users/confirm/ I get Your account has been activated. Is there any way that I can set this too, Sorry you have not entered a code?

Comment: If you're receiving that message using the above code, your UserModel::confirm_user method is returning true for a blank activation code.

Comment: Thanks Jess, so I guess this approach helped or solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you do need to call the [`validation_errors()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#theform) helper (or one of Codeigniter's other helpers for error generation) in your view file.

```
// in view file
<form>
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  <!-- rest of form... -->
</form>
```

If you're calling `validation_errors()` and still not seeing output, it's probably because validation isn't running. Prior to calling the view, you need to run form validation:

```
// in controller action function
$this->form_validation->run();
```

With the code you provided above, that still won't quite take care of things--you haven't actually set up any rules for validation. You'll want to read up on the [validation guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules), but the general approach looks like this:

```
// in controller action function
$this->form_validation->add_rules('my_field', 'My Field Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->run();
```

You may be wondering what `add_rules` is actually testing. In Codeigniter, it's generally designed to work on any form data `$_POST`ed from a form. To use it directly on a model (as it looks like you're trying to do) will take some hacking, and it may be easiest to just use a flag variable and a message string:

```
function confirm($activateCode = '') {

  $error = false;
  $message = '';

  if($activateCode == '')
  {
    $error = true;
    $message = 'Sorry you did not have a correct Activation Code.';
  }

  $userConfirmed = $this->users_model->confirm_user($activateCode);

  if($userConfirmed)
  {
    $message = 'Thanks your account is now active you may login!';
  }
  else
  {
    $error = true;
    $message = 'I am sorry we do not have any details with that Activation Code';
  }

  $data['error'] = $error;
  $data['message'] = $message
}
```

In view:

```
<?php if ($message != ''): ?>
<?php if ($error): ?>
  ERROR: <?php echo $message; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  SUCCESS: <?php echo $message; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey,  I have included my view :)

Comment: And updated the answer to match! The `form_validation` library's designed to solve a different problem than you're trying to use it for here--I hope the alternative I've suggested here meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks Mate,  I have updated my question as I am still not getting a response :)

Comment: One thing I noticed quickly is a syntax error here in your updated view: <?php $confirmMessage?>. Did you mean <?php echo $confirmMessage; ?>

Comment: Thanks,  But that did not solve the issue.  I have just done a var_dump() and got the following: bool(false) string(48) "Thanks your account is now active you may login!"

Comment: ok,  I fixed that missed an echo & a ; but now I just get  Thanks your account is now active you may login! when I am using just users/confirm/

Comment: can you confirm the value of `$activateCode`? If it's not "", then the conditional expression testing whether it's empty or not will fail.

Comment: its a random generated string that is created during the sign up process http://cl.ly/1U083O0F151W0t0T3a0f

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear--looking for the value when it *should* be empty (e.g., when the user browses to users/confirm/ with no code specified). Just want to make sure it's actually an empty string :-)

Comment: yep thats what I have now -> should be not a value and display Sorry you did not have a correct Activation Code

Comment: Ok, so if you `echo` out `$activateCode` when the page loads, you can confirm it's blank?

Comment: I have just done a var_dump on the /confirm/ and got `bool(false)`.  When I run the `$activateCode` i get `string(10) "TdjxQqRYHS"`

Comment: That's what `$activateCode` comes out to with out that third URI segment factored in? We may have to rethink the `if($activateCode == '')` bit if `$activateCode` isn't actually blank. I wonder where `TdjxQetc` are coming from, though..

Comment: Hmm, your model code looks ok. I've adjusted the controller method in my answer above to pull `$activateCode` straight from the router rather than trying to parse it with the URI helper. That ought to clear up any problems from an undefined parameter.